# Why can't nasm find include statements from cmake

Tags: cmake, nasm

I have a modular boot loader i'm toying with. I felt it would be more of a pain setting it up to use gas than to port nasm to cmake. It seems not to be that way. NAsm is unable to find the include file. What am I missing?

The entire code can be found in [This Github Repo](https://github.com/CodeGrimoire/failingcmake)

Here is the project layout:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── Failing_module
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── Print.inc
    └── Stage1
        └── Stage1.asm
```

./CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(fails C ASM_NASM)
add_subdirectory(Failing_module)
```

Failing_module/CMakeLists.txt:

```
enable_language(ASM_NASM)
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT bin)

set(module_SRCS Stage1/Stage1.asm)

set(CMAKE_NASM_LINK_EXECUTABLE nasm)
add_executable(Stage1.bin ${module_SRCS})
set_target_properties(Stage1.bin PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE NASM)
install(TARGETS Stage1.bin DESTINATION bin)
```

Failing_module/Stage1/Stage1.asm:

```
bits 16

jmp main

%include "Print.inc"
msgHello db "Hello World", 0x00

main:
    mov s, msgHello
    call Print
```

Failing_module/Print.inc

```
Print:
    lodsb
    or  al, al
    jz  PrintDone
    mov ah, 0x0E
    int 0x10
    jmp Print
PrintDone:
    ret
```

The output of cmake is the following:

```
Failing_module/Stage1/Stage1.asm:6: fatal: unable to open include file `Print.inc'
make[2]: *** [Failing_module/CMakeFiles/Stage1.bin.dir/build.make:63:  Failing_module/CMakeFiles/Stage1.bin.dir/Stage1/Stage1.asm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:86: Failing_module/CMakeFiles/Stage1.bin.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:128: all] Error 2
```

***EDIT*** Should compile by manual means now. This makes it a SSCCE

Comment: You absolutely sure the exact file name `Print.inc` exists specifically in `Failing_module` directory? Even if you get past this error, your code won't assemble as this is invalid `mov si "Hello World"` . You have to create a string of bytes at a label (after your code) with `Hello World` in it and use the name of that label with something like `mov si, hello`

Comment: Dead sure that the Print.inc is in fact named that and in the correct place. I wrote this as an example. I have had the actual code compile through manual means.

Comment: You sure this is the error message you get and not something else?There is no way the first first of the NASM file you gave would have assembled since it had improper syntax.

Comment: Yes I am sure. https://ibin.co/2txJI9WRDEV2.png
The full code is on github and updated.

Comment: I am using CLion for this. When I tried it from terminal it worked...

Comment: On further research it only builds if cmake is ran in the same directory.

Comment: You never mentioned CLion at all. When I ran it from the directory directly it had no issue with `Print.inc` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122629/discussion-between-luke-smith-and-michael-petch).

Comment: Assembling is executed under `<build-dir>/Failing_module/CMakeFiles`, but your include file is in `<source-dir>/Failing_module`. Normally you need proper call to `include_directories` for include file being discoverable.

Comment: You mention that compiling from command line works: can you show the exact command line?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'll try that, thanks.
@Antonio when I used `cmake ../../repos/failingcmake && make` but `cmake . && make` works if in the same dir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that some strictness in CMake interacts poorly with a flaw in NASM. CMake insists that search paths (such as `%include` paths) do not have a trailing slash. `nasm` insists that search paths (given with a `-I` option) do have a trailing slash. CMake won't be changed; its developers [do not regard this as a CMake bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/12919). They are right: `nasm` should not insist that include paths have a trailing slash. [The `nasm` fault](https://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392205) has been known for several years.

I managed to work around this issue by hiding the search path as a normal compile option:

```
 add_compile_options(-I ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ )
 add_library( my_lib STATIC "my_source.asm" )
```

Comment: It is supposed to be fixed in the nasm version 2.14.